# Banach spaces and surjective operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two Banach spaces and $T \in L(X,Y)$ be surjective. Then there exists a constant $C>0$ so that for every $y\in Y$ there exists a $x\in X$ with $Tx=y$ and that the following is true: $||x||_X \leq C||y||_Y$.

My thoughts: Surjection would mean that $\forall y\in Y \exists x \in X : Tx=y$. This is pretty much the first statement?

I'm not sure about the constant. Since $X,Y$ are banach spaces, I've thought of equivalent norms but I'm unsure how to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ \pi: X \to X/N(T)$ be defined by $\pi(x):=x+N(T).$

$N(T)$ denotes the kernel of $T$.

We equip the quotient space $X/N(T)$ with the quotient norm  $|| \cdot ||$. Then this space is a Banach space.

Further we define the linear mapping $T_0: X/N(T) \to Y$ by $T_0(x+N(T)) :=Tx.$

Show that $T_0$ is bounded and bijective. Since $X/N(T)$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, $T_0^{-1}$ is bounded.

If $y \in Y$ there exists $x_0 \in X$ with $Tx_0=y$, hence $y=T_0(x_0+N(T))$, thus

$$x_0+N(T)=T_0^{-1}y.$$

Therefore

$$||x_0+N(T)|| \le ||T_0^{-1}|| \cdot ||y||_Y.$$

The definition of the quotient norm now gives some $x \in x_0+N(T)$ such that

$$||x||_X \le (||T_0^{-1}|| +1)\cdot ||y||_Y.$$

Since $x-x_0 \in N(T)$, we have $Tx=Tx_0=y.$

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain the last line? I don't see why this is true.

Comment: the definition of the quotient norm is:  $||x+N(T)||= \inf \{||z||_X: z \in x+N(T) \}$

Comment: $||x+N(T)||=\inf_{n \in N} ||x+n||_X$

Comment: Also why is $T_0$ bijective? Because if it were and $X/N(T)$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, this would imply that the inverse is continuous which would mean that it is bounded? Is that correct?

Comment: $T$ is bounded $ \iff T$ is continuous.

Comment: Since $T$ is surjective, $T_0$ is surjective. It is now your job to show that $T_0$ is injective.

Comment: Ok done, but I still don't see where the "+ 1" comes from in your last line. Why do I add an extra $||y||_Y$?

Comment: You can not garantee that $||x||_X \le ||T_0^{-1}|| \cdot ||y||_Y.$

Comment: In which case would that inequality be wrong? Could you give an example?

Comment: I have made an edit !

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the open mapping theorem: Let $K(x,r)$ denote the open ball with center $x$ and radius $r$. Since $T$ is surjective it is open. Thus there is some $r>0$ such that $K(0,r) \subseteq T(K(0,1))$. Let $y \in Y$ (w.l.o.g. $y \not=0$). Then $\frac{r}{2\|y\|}y \in K(0,r)$. Thus for some $z \in K(0,1)$ we have $Tz=\frac{r}{2\|y\|}y$, that is $y = T(\frac{2\|y\|}{r}z)$. Now $x:=\frac{2\|y\|}{r}z$ satisfies $Tx=y$ and $\|x\| \le \frac{2}{r}\|y\|$, so you can choose $C=\frac{2}{r}$.